# jQuery continuously loop all scripts after ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have problem when I call one function in jQuery. With firebug I debug my code and after executing `Post.profilePost()` all script start looping continuously and never stop. Check picture:

[image]

So i have profile page where i want to load all posts.

```
profilePost: function() {

    setTimeout( function() { $('.content-loader').show(); },100 );
    setTimeout( function() {
        $('.content-loader').hide();
        $("#profile-posts-container").load(baseurl + '/profile/posts', function() {
            $(".home-posts").fadeIn("slow");
        });
    }, 4000 );

}

    init: function() { 
           // Post.homePost();
            Post.profilePost();
    }

<div id="profile-posts-container">
    <div class="content-loader"></div>
</div>
```

And in document ready I call `Post.init();`
All work good and posts is loaded but to many request start looping after this. What can be the problem?

Comment: Add some console.log or alert, and check how many times this code will fired.

Comment: I try that. Its never stop!!!

Comment: Where you added the log/alert ? in `init`?

Comment: in `init: function();`

Comment: Maybe we need to see all your codes, but could you please comment all the codes in `init` and left just that log/alert?

Comment: deam this is inposible. I comment and delete all other and leave just this two function `init()` and `profilePosts()` and again looping

Comment: Are you sure you linked the codes just once in your page?

Comment: If you deleted all codes, so there is no error with `ajax`, if the log/alert() runs more than once, so I think you linked the codes more than once. or you have some other codes. please make this clear.

Comment: This is happend only when i call this function `profilePosts()`  whitout that function all work fantastic....  I will try to debug more

Comment: try this: $('...').one('load', function(){...}), btw there is no need to `setTimeout`, you can show the loader first and hide than in `load callback`, I mean after this line: `$(".home-posts").fadeIn("slow");`

Comment: Deam you right. When i call `load()` i load that page but that page automticly extend static header

Comment: So, everything okay now?

Comment: yap, now work perfect. It seems that i need a break, tired and not thinking :)